# MDX: How to calculate earned premium (i.e. prorata a measure between two time dimensions)

Tags: mdx

A simple cube has 1 measure and three time dimensions:

- [Measures].[Amount Paid]
- [Date Paid]
- [Cover Start Date]
- [Cover End Date]

Earned Premium = 
    0% if Cover Start Date is before the period in question
  100% if Cover End Date has passed
       else [Cover End - Cover Start] * Days Since Start

For any given cell, how do I traverse all the start and end dates and determine what the amount earned for a period is?

Comment: Mark, what OLAP server are you using ? .. the issue here is how to transform your premium into something than can be aggregated over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume other dimension are missing, e.g. one like [ContractId], if no what comes after doesn't make real sense.

The problem here is that your actual measure,earned premium, is a function (Amount Paid, Cover Start Date, Cover End Date, date) and this for each deal. You can not aggregate over a set of deals at once as the function is not associative - or something like this :-).

So I would feed my cube with the premium for each deal over the period [Cover Start Date], [Cover End Date] with the daily premium for this contract. Once you've this you can easily aggregate this measure over your dimensions. -> Now daily premium is not anymore a function of Cover dates..

MDX is not a real calculation engine, so you're pushing the system out of it's limit. Solving this with scopes, calculated measures can produce an amazingly slow cube...